# Question on Continuous Differentiability under Expectation

Tags: probability, analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable in $x \in \Re$ a.e.. Let $D$ be a continuous random variable on $\Re$.  Also, assume that $E_D(f(x-D))$ exist for all $x$.  Can we say that $g(x) = E_D(f(x-D))$ is continuously differentiable for all $x$?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the Heaviside function, then $E_D(f(x-D))$ is the cdf of D, which is continuously differentiable. Does the characteristic function fit into the form $E_D(f(x-D))$?

Comment: It may, but then it'll be differentiable. Bad example.